# How to get code from Github but don't want to commit from local?

Tags: github, github-for-windows

How to get code from github using github desktop for windows?

I want to get latest code everytime from live repostiory as everyone commit there changes and it should be lock with my local changes. I mean I don't want to commit my local changes to live repository.

How to setup this thing?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to get updates to your Git project, but you want to leave your local branches alone.

A `git pull` is out of the question. A `git pull` is a `fetch` to update your remote branches, plus a `merge` to update your locals. Instead, only use [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes#Fetching-and-Pulling-from-Your-Remotes). This will update only your remote branches (ie. your copy of the Github repository), but leave all your local branches alone.